# Website monitor display issue

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a website that displays differently on different monitors.
Desktop:
[image: desktop]
Laptop:
[image: Laptop]

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="Links">
<a href="About.html"><img src="Slideshow/About.png" width="140em" /></a> 
<br /><br />
<a href="Contact.html"><img src="Slideshow/Contact.fw.png"  width="140em" /></a>
<br /><br />
<a href="Services.html"><img src="Slideshow/Services.fw.png"  width="140em" /></a>
</div>

<div id="mainText">
<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>If you want to contact me please call at <b>1.800.SUCCESS</b> or use the form below to sned me an email!</p>
</div>





<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table id="conTable">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
```

CSS

```
    body
{

        background-image:url(Pictures/background.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:100%;

}
    #mainText
    {

    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    left: 14em;

}
#conTable
{

    left:14em;
    top:8em;
    position:absolute;
}

#Banner
    {
            position:absolute;
            padding-left:40%;
    }
#Links
    {
            position:absolute;
            float:left;
            width:50px;

    }
```

Can anyone please tell me why things look different on my laptop then it does on my desktop and how to fix it. As you can see from the pictures everything on my laptop is shifted to the left.

Comment: I bet either the laptop browser is zoomed in or the desktop browser is zoomed out. Try pressing Ctrl-0 in both of them.

Comment: @Juhana both zoom levels are 100%

Comment: I see differents urls on images. Are you sure that files on both are the same?

Comment: @WooCaSh They are 2 different images of the same webpage. one is from a desktop and one is from a laptop

Comment: @TheAce One is from local disk and another from server. Can you test both from server? And make sure that you disable cache in Chrome DevTools ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping a "Relative" #container around all your "absolute" divs. I've adjusted your code below:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="Links">
<a href="About.html"><img src="Slideshow/About.png" width="140em" /></a> 
<br /><br />
<a href="Contact.html"><img src="Slideshow/Contact.fw.png"  width="140em" /></a>
<br /><br />
<a href="Services.html"><img src="Slideshow/Services.fw.png"  width="140em" /></a>
</div>

<div id="mainText">
<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>If you want to contact me please call at <b>1.800.SUCCESS</b> or use the form below to sned me an email!</p>
</div>


<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table id="conTable">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{

        background-image:url(Pictures/background.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:100%;

}
    #mainText
    {

    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    left: 14em;

}
#conTable
{

    left:14em;
    top:8em;
    position:absolute;
}

#Banner
    {
            position:absolute;
            padding-left:40%;
    }
#Links
    {
            position:absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width:50px;

    }
    #container {position: relative; width: 100%}
```